# SQL: SET primary record based on a union all join

Tags: sql, pervasive, pervasive-sql

I have two pervasive databases that I join in.  These two databases may have the same Social Security Numbers.  I am trying to set a primary record to each of these multiple records.  The primary record should be the earliest Orig_Hire date and Active = 'A'

```
database_1.demographics
Ss_No        Orig_Hire    Active
111-00-1111  2015-01-01   A
111-00-1111  2014-01-01   T
111-00-1111  2015-08-07   A

database_2.demographics
Ss_No        Orig_Hire    Active
111-00-1111  2013-01-01   T
111-00-1111  2012-01-01   T
```

Here is my query:

```
SELECT demo.*, 
(select (some logic) from demo WHERE GROUP BY Ss_No) As Primary_Record //this doesnt work
FROM
    (SELECT Ss_No, Orig_Hire, Active FROM database_1.demographics
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Ss_No, Orig_Hire, Active FROM database_2.demographics) demo
```

Is there another, better way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Also: clarify what means "better". Do you have performance problem or logic problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need do this in two parts.

First found the min value and then get the record matching that min.

Let simplify your question calling your union `demo`

```
SELECT Ss_No, Orig_Hire, Active FROM database_1.demographics
UNION ALL
SELECT Ss_No, Orig_Hire, Active FROM database_2.demographics
```

So your logic to find the `MIN` date for each `SSN` would be

```
SELECT Ss_No, MIN(Orig_Hire) as Orig_Hire    
FROM demo
WHERE Active = 'A'
GROUP BY Ss_No
```

Now you need find the complete record.

```
SELECT demo.*
FROM demo
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT Ss_No, MIN(Orig_Hire) as Orig_Hire    
    FROM demo
    WHERE Active = 'A'
    GROUP BY Ss_No
    ) min_hire
  ON demo.Orig_Hire = min_hire.Orig_Hire  
 AND demo.Ss_No = min_hire.Ss_No
```

- In case no exist `MIN(Orig_Hire)` with `Active = 'A'` you will get some `Ss_no` with null values and you should validate those.
- Also this assume a Ss_No doesnt have multiple rows for same `MIN(Orig_Hire) and Active = 'A'`

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by using PHP.  This is the most simple way I came up with.

```
$sql = "SELECT Ss_No, Orig_Hire, Active FROM database_1.demographics
        UNION ALL
        SELECT Ss_No, Orig_Hire, Active FROM database_2.demographics
        ORDER BY 1,3,2 ASC"; /* ORDERBY is important since we are setting the first record*/

$sth = $apex->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute();

$sth->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$SSN = '';

foreach ($sth as $row) {
    if($row['SSN'] != $SSN) {
        $row['IsPrimaryAssignment'] = 1;
    } else {
        $row['IsPrimaryAssignment'] = 0;
    }
    $SSN = $row['SSN'];
}
```